# MVC HttpDelete Verb causing 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, httphandler

I'm encounting a method now allowed exception when calling a controller action which accepts the Delete verb.

I thought the problem was that the HandlerMappings in IIS 7.0 were wrong and when I looked
at:

```
ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit
ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit
ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
```

Sure enough they didn't accept the DELETE verb. I added this to the list of Verbs but I am still getting an error so I'm at a loss as to why this is the case. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered this issue was being caused by the WebDav module. I removed this from my web.config and this resolved the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this helps someone else!